# Resize wallpaper to desired size without changing the aspect-ratio

Tags: gimp, resize, scale

I want an image of size 4551x8001 px to turn into 16:9 format, i thought scaling would work, but it just stretches the image.
How can achieve this?
Changing the size leads to the gray boxes alternating, but i can overlay a black background behind it.
[This is the image](https://wallpapercave.com/w/wp8157924), i would just like to turn it into 16:9 format without losing quality.(So 14224x8001)

Comment: Do you really need a 113 megapixel image? If you're using this for desktop wallpaper all you need is the pixel dimensions of your screen. The method is the same either way, but the end result will be far less of a graphics hit.

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is. It sounds like you already found the solution: You change the image size and get transparent background (visualized with a gray checkered pattern) and then you can add a black layer behind to fill the empty space. What doesn't work?

Comment: There are two slight problems with doing that - the background isn't black & the image contains some garbage white pixels on the edges… but other than that, yup. Takes about 1 minute in photoshop, but I don't have the patience to ever try figure out how to do anything in Gimp ;)

Comment: For some reason, the black layer does not get shown correctly, does not apear ...

Comment: Thank you all for your help, i found the mistake, i thought opacity 0.0 would mean no transparency, and set the layer below to 0.0, and the endresult was not what i expected :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems

1. That size image would be far too big. Massive in fact. Don't create such large images for on-screen use. It's absolutely unnecessary. Find the size (in pixels) of the screen/device the wallpaper is going to be used on. That should be the size you need. Raster images always look best at the native size and resolution of the device they are being viewed on.
2. The image is probably the wrong aspect ratio.  You'd need to crop it to the correct aspect ratio first, then scale if necessary, while maintaining the aspect ratio, or the image will be distorted.
3. You can't rescale (resample) raster images without some degradation in quality. You can't get more detail in an image by scaling it up, and you will lose detail if scaling down.

In GIMP the crop tool has a fixed aspect ratio option. You can type in 16:9 in there to crop it that way.

Do *Image > Scale Image*  to resize an image if absolutely necessary. Don't uncheck the aspect ratio locks, and the aspect ratio will be maintained.

Comment: +1 but it does need padding L/R to be able to crop to 16:9, then ends up at a massive 8k x 4.5k, so it's going to definitely need some down-sampling to get to a reasonable screen resolution.

Comment: @Tesujin Thanks. Yeah, I wasn't particularly answering with the OP's particular image in mind. This isn't a tutorial . . . rather just a very general how to crop and rescale to an aspect ratio. Other work may be necessary to fit a square peg in a round hole ;)

Comment: I know about this, the actual way to do it is what i am missing. What you described is not really what i am seeing in GIMP, where do i have to click what? 
Thank you for your advice, seriously, but i am missing the way to actually do it...

Comment: Thank you all for your help, i found the mistake, i thought opacity 0.0 would mean no transparency, and set the layer below to 0.0, and the endresult was not what i expected :)